# removeIf() of List is not working as intended

Tags: java, arraylist

Whenever I try to remove an element from a `List` using **list.removeIf(condition)** it throws `UnsupportedOperationException`:

```
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) 
    {
        String[] stringArray = new String[]{"A","B","C","D"}; 
        List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(stringArray); 
        stringList.forEach(System.out::println); 
        stringList.removeIf((String string) -> string.equals("B")); 
        stringList.forEach(System.out::println); 
    }
}
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: It is throwing as I mentioned above

Answer (score 9):

`Arrays.asList` returns a fixed sized `List` - backed by the array you pass in - so, just as you can't remove (or add) elements from an array, you can't remove (or add) elements from the List.

Use a `java.util.ArrayList` in order to be able to remove elements:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(stringArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.asList method returns an ArrayList of type java.util.Arrays.ArrayList (which is read only and fixed size) and not the classic java.util.ArrayList (resizable and item-removable)